# An example of infinitely differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by the following formula: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right), & |x|<1 \\
0, & |x|\geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable.

**Proof:** I was able to show that $f'(x)$ exists for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)\times \left(\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\right), & |x|<1 \\
0, & |x|\geq 1
\end{cases}$$

I was wondering is there any way to write explicit formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$.

I would be very thankful of someone can show the detailed proof of this problem.

Comment: See on a simpler example, for the intuition. Take $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. It's obviously $\mathcal C^\infty $ on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.  For $x>0$, $f^{(n)}(x)$ is something of the form $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha _i}{x^k}$ for some $\alpha _i\in\mathbb R$. Taking $x\to 0^+$ yields $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. Same if $x<0$. Therefore $f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @Surb, why the limit of $f^{(n)}(x)$ as $x\to 0+$ is just $f^{(n)}(0)$? I guess we definitely need more details to clarify this equality.

Comment: **Homework :** Suppose $f'$ is continuous on $(a-\varepsilon ,a+\varepsilon )\setminus \{a\}$. If $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exist, then $f$ is derivable at $a$ and $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of the desired claim, the explicit formula is not needed and rather it is sufficient to know (i.e., prove by induction) that
$$ f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac1{(x-1)^2}-\frac1{(x+1)^2}\right)\times P_n(\frac1{x-1},\frac1{x+1}),&|x|<1\\0,&|x|\ge 1\end{cases}$$
where $P_n(x,y)$ is a polynomial. This is clear with $P_0(x,y)=1$ from the problem statement, and you already managed to show this for $n=1$ with $P_1(x,y)=2x^3+2y^3$. But we do not need to know $P_n$ explicitly, it suffices to know that it is a polynomial.